# How to set color to Rectangle drawn with html5?

Tags: html

I'm learning about Html5.

```
<html>
<body>
<canvas id="canvas1" width="300" height="200"></canvas>
<script>
 var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas1");
 var cxt = canvas.getContext("2d");

 context.fillRect(0, 0, 150, 100);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

How to set color for this Rectangle?

Comment: Perhaps you merely forgot (to paste) it, but always use the HTML 5 Doctype, as this will trigger quirks mode. `<!DOCTYPE html>`.

Answer (score 4):

```
ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(200,0,0)";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 150, 100);
```

fillStyle must be called before fillRect

And if you're not already using it:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/canvas_tutorial